# ListView delete item by name using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I was just wondering if it was possible to delete an item from a listview just knowing its text name (as in listbox.text) without the need to know the index or have it selected/highlighted?

```
 Dim lvi As ListViewItem
 Dim lvi2 As ListViewItem

    For Each lvi In lstMaster.Items
        For Each lvi2 In lstNew.Items
            If lvi.Text = lvi2.text Then
                'Remove the item using its TEXT..
                'Eample:
                'lstMaster        | lstNew
                '--------------------------------------
                'Bob              | Jenny
                'Jason            |
                'Jenny            |
                'Zac              |
                '--------------------------------------
                'The program should delete "Jenny" from the lstMaster....
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Thanks!

David

Comment: Bah!  Wanted to put code so I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see why you couldn't use the text property.  Is there any reason why you cant do this though:

```
If lvi.Text = lvi2.Text Then
    lstMaster.Items.Remove(lvi)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you:

```vb
Dim lvw As New ListView()

lvw.Items.AddRange({New ListViewItem("Item 1"),
                    New ListViewItem("Item 2"),
                    New ListViewItem("Item 3")})

lvw.Items.Remove((From i In lvw.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem)() 
                  Where i.Text = "Item 1").First)
```

It uses LINQ to find the item with the text "Item 1" and then it removes it from the ListView's ListViewItemCollection (the `Items` property).

The minor caveat here is that there must be an Item with the text "Item 1" otherwise the `First()` extension method will fail. If you are unsure, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` or pre-check the LINQ statement contains a value before proceeding with the item removal.

### Edit

This is the updated code to match your updated requirement:

```
For Each lvi in lstNew.Items
    Dim masterItem = From i in lstMaster.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem)()
                     Where i.Text = lvi.Text
    
    If masterItem.Any Then
        lstMaster.Items.Remove(masterItem.First)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Pete beat you to the punch but its pretty much the same so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the list from which you want to delete items, like this:

```
For Each lvi In lstMaster.Items.ToList
    For Each lvi2 In lstNew.Items
        If lvi.Text = lvi2.text Then
            lstMaster.Items.Remove(lvi)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

That way you don't have the problem of deleting items from the list you're currently enumerating.

Comment: Almost but Pete beat you to the punch! Thanks anyways, Meta-Knight!